# Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm and cpan not found the c compiler to generate

Tags: linux, perl, synology, xml-libxml

I need LibXML in a Linux Machine and have the next error like other posts:

```
Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC
```

I saw the solution, but the problem that I have is that when try generate the library with cpan, show error that not found the compiler. I was looking the answer for my problem, and I found the way to install, with apt-get or mcpan, but not get apt-get or aptitude commands, I only can with ipkg install perl_libXML or with cpan.

The error with cpan is the next:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install XML::LibXML
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 01 Nov 2014 19:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::LibXML'
Running make for S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0117.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0117.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0117.tar.gz

Use of uninitialized value $config_val in pattern match (m//) at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 372.
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 92.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 92.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0117.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
Failed during this command:
 SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0117.tar.gz             : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 512

cpan[2]>
```

I not know why with ipkg the installation is ok but after not work. I think with cpan would work if the process would found the c compiler, but I not know which is the problem or how tell to cpan the path to the compiler or if is neccesary install it.

I try to manual compile and this is the result, but I not understand why no funda the compilar, I have severas compiler un the sistem. Ťhe error is :

```
root@Linux: ~/.cpan/build/XML-LibXML-2.0117-tF5gWA # perl Makefile.PL DEBUG=1
Use of uninitialized value $config_val in pattern match (m//) at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 372.
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 92.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 92.
root@Kubyx: ~/.cpan/build/XML-LibXML-2.0117-tF5gWA #
```

Can you help me to solve the problem or compile by hand?

Comment: Most perl modules don't need a C compiler to install. This one does.

Comment: Ok, I know this, but the problem is I need cpan find the compiler, I was looking for this and I can give more information about the error, I see this error in a module dependencie and I can play the error with this: perl -MDevel::CheckLib
Use of uninitialized value $config_val in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/site_perl/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 369.
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted." I thing the compiler is ok, but one modulo need more information in any variable, but I not know how and where I have to put it

Comment: did you find the solution for it... am facing the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my system.

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc is the executable to GCC binary supplied as argument to perl. So Devel::CheckLib is not finding the C compiler once my distro Ubuntu, don't create alternatives to x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc using gcc-5, version where I am using.

The workaround was to change to /usr/bin and create a symlink from x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc to x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-5.

This is not the first time that I need symlink to alternative names of GCC. Ubuntu distro should create an alternative to all gcc version available and automatically manage the alternatives using update-alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter same error when install the XML::Parser:

```
Running install for module 'XML::Parser'
Checksum for /home/sss/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.46.tar.gz ok
Configuring T/TO/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.46.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 4.
```

But I build a conda env and install by conda and work well. May work well with installing XML::LibXML.

- build and activate conda env

```sh
conda create -n perl5 perl=5.26
conda activate perl5
```

- Install XML::Parser by conda rather than cpan, and it will install the XML::Parser dependent libraries `expat` and `libxml2` auto.

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 perl-xml-parser
# conda install XML::LibXML may be work
conda install -c bioconda perl-xml-libxml
```

- Test the package install success

```sh
perl -MXML::Parser -e ''
perl -MXML::LibXML -e ''
```